# which certificate and provisioning profile are used to sign my application?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm try to develop an iOS app and the current Build Settings are:
Code Signing Identity
  Debug: Don't code sign
    Any SDK: iOS Developer
  Release: Don't code sign
    Any SDK: iOS Developer
Provisioning Profile: None

How come that I'm still able to run the app on my iPad even though I've not selected any Provisioning Profile and selected "Don't code sign" for the Debug setting?

Is there a way to see which profile was selected for this app (even though I didn't select any)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see what code signing identity and profile are being used by looking at the build logs in Xcode. Go to View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator. Find your latest build and select "All Messages" at the top of the log. Scroll down towards the bottom of the log and you should see a "CodeSign app_name.app" entry. click on that and expand it by clicking the 3 little lines on the right side. The log will then say "Using code signing identity "foo" and provisioning profile "bar"

Comment: In the new menus in xCode 7: View->Navigators->Show Report Navigator